# How to save array of struct with vector in binary C++

Tags: c++, vector, struct, binaryfiles

I need to save an array of struct in a binary file. but there is some problem! I have some 3d array of vector in my struct! this is my struct :

```
struct State
{
    vector<bool> ***value;
    vector<int> ***rfcCLB2Bits;
    State()
    {
      new3dArray(value , 60 , 100 , 2);
      new3dArray(rfcCLB2Bits , 60 , 100 , 2);
    }

};
```

and you may want to see new3dArray function :

```
template <class T>
void new3dArray(T ***&u3d, int nx , int ny , int nz)
{
    u3d = new T ** [nx];
    if (NULL == u3d)
    {
      cout <<"erro3"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++)
        {
            u3d[i] = new T *[ny];
            if (NULL == u3d[i])
            {
                cout <<"erro4"<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++)
                {
                    u3d[i][j] = new T [nz];
                    if (NULL == u3d[i][j])
                    {
                        cout <<"erro5"<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

at last my code for saving and loading :

```
int main()
{
    State *states;
    int k ;
    cin >> k;
    states = new State[k];

    ...

    string location = "save1.bin";
    ofstream fs(location, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app);
    fs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(states), sizeof(states));
    fs.close();

    ...

    ifstream file (location, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read ((char*)&states, sizeof(states));
        file.close();
    }

    ...
}
```

but it didnt work! what I must to do?

Comment: Why are you doing `vector<bool> ***` and `vector<int> ***`? You can already use `vector` so why not use them instead of dynamic arrays?

Comment: You should use `vector < vector < vector < vector < bool > > > >` instead of `vector<bool>***`.

Comment: `vector<bool> ***value;` is the worst thing I've ever seen in C++ code (apart from the lack of formatting/indentation).

Comment: Avoid using vector of bools. Ref. -Scott Meyer's Item 18

Comment: Two things. First, `std::vector<bool>` doesn't fully behave like a vector, so you *might* have issues with it, depending on what you do. Second, [three star programming](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) isn't as cool as it might seem at first. You should really avoid all these pointers to pointers. It will make your code hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: No problem!you can assume I use `vector < vector < vector < vector < bool > > > >` insted of `vector<bool>***` ! I cant save my struct yet!